# Non-stationary spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, metric-tensor

What is an example for a spacetime that is non-stationary that is considered as a description of something in nature?

So far all the spacetimes I encounted have always been stationary (Schwartzschild, FRW, Kerr, etc.).

Comment: The most general, non-static axially symmetric metric can be reduced to the form $ds^2=-e^\alpha dr^2-e^\beta d\theta^2-e^\gamma d\phi^2 + e^\delta dt^2$ where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and $\delta$ are functions of $r,\theta,t$ alone.

Comment: @JamalS Kerr is non-static, axisymmetric and does have off-diagonal terms.

Comment: @auxsvr: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02450444

Comment: @JamalS This is wrong, quoting from Wald, p. 119: "A stationary but nonstatic metric unavoidably must have $dt dx^\mu$ cross terms in any coordinate system which uses the Killing parameter as one of the coordinates" and $t$ is a Killing parameter for a stationary metric. We infer that the inexistence of hypersurfaces orthogonal to the orbits of isometry generated by the Killing vector $\partial_\phi$ implies that you must have cross terms of the form $d \phi dx^\mu$ in the metric. The cross terms have physical significance, you cannot remove them in general.

Comment: Also, see [this](http://mnras.oxfordjournals.org/content/406/3/2047.full.pdf+html) for details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest physical example is just given by FRW (differently from what you wrote!) models describing the large scale of the universe:
$$ds^2 = -d\tau^2 + a(\tau)^2 d\Sigma^2\:.$$
If $a$ is not constant (as it happens in our universe) $\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}$ is not a Killing vector. In general, these metrics do not admit local or global timelike Killing vectors (even different from $\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}$).
Another case is the spacetime of a  collapsing star in the absence of spherical symmetry (otherwise Birkhoff's theorem would imply that the metric is stationary in a region).

Comment: Birkhoff not Birkov

Answer (score 0):

While the spacetime surrounding a one-dimensional mass with finite length is stationary (not static), the spacetime surrounding it when it is rotating will be non-stationary. Gravitational waves will travel away from the mass. For a point mass the surrounding spacetime is static. For rotating, spherically symmetrically distributed matter, the surrounding spacetime is non-stationary also. Due to frame dragging gravitational waves will appear.